# Python: how do I filter data as long as a group contains any of a particular value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'VisitID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4], 'Item':['A','B','C','D','A','D','B','B','C','D','C']})
```

I have a dataset like this:

```
VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
3       | B    |
3       | C    |
4       | D    |
4       | C    |
```

I want to return VisitID rows as long as that VisitID had a occurrence of item A OR B. How do I go about? Expected Result:

```
VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
3       | B    |
3       | C    |
```

In R, I can do this via

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(VisitID) %>% filter(any(Item %in% c('A', 'B')))
```

How can I perform this in Python? 
Something like `df.groupby(['VisitID']).query(any(['A','B']))?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is similar, just use `groupby.filter`:

```
df.groupby('VisitID').filter(lambda g: g.Item.isin(['A','B']).any())

   VisitID Item
0        1    A
1        1    B
2        1    C
3        1    D
4        2    A
5        2    D
6        2    B
7        3    B
8        3    C
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract groups contains **either** we can just use `groupby().transform('any')` on `isin()`:

```
s = (df.Item.isin(['A','B'])
       .groupby(df['VisitID']).transform('any')
    )
df[s]
```

Output:

```
   VisitID Item
0        1    A
1        1    B
2        1    C
3        1    D
4        2    A
5        2    D
6        2    B
7        3    B
8        3    C
```